# Looping in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I echo `1, 2, 3, 4, ....` with a twig counter? I can accomplish it with dirty code below but is there a better way?

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for brand in brands %}
    {% set i = i + 1 %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I used `{{ cycle(["even", "odd"], loop.index) }}` but only getting even or odd.

Also checked Twig [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) and [range](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `loop.index0` or `loop.index` variable, [as mentioned in the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

```
{% for brand in brands %}
    {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I never though about removing cycle part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `{{ loop.index }}` or `{{ loop.index0 }}`if you need it to be 0 indexed